# How to get autocomplete result with Selenium::Remote::Driver

Tags: perl, selenium, firefox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i want to write a little script to grab and play around with the results of the autocomplete of an input field.
So I find a principal solution with Selenium::Firefox, that base on module [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver), but the description of the methods is without any examples.

I have this basic example, that is able to open google and insert a search string.
Then you can see that a result list is suggested and i want to get this list.
But i have no idea how this can be obtained?

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Firefox;

my $mech = Selenium::Firefox->new( 
    startup_timeout => 20,
    firefox_binary => '/srv/bin/firefox.62.0/firefox',
    binary => '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver',
    marionette_enabled => 1
);

my $search = "perl";
my $url = "https://www.google.com/";

$mech->get($url);

$mech->find_element_by_name("q");

sleep(3);
my $result = $mech->get_active_element();
$result->send_keys($search);

sleep (10);

$mech->shutdown_binary;
exit 0;
```

I could find no examples to use this Perl module - and there are more questions for it.
As for instance: [find_element](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver#find_element) 
How can i turn on the warnings instead of killing the script?
Or how can i step through the objects of the wep page?
Is it possible to connect to an already opened browser?

The description of the module is not understandable for people who are not experts and the authors did not answer to questions so far.
But my hope is that experts here can give me a hint?

Comment: *"How can i turn on the warnings instead of killing the script?"*: you encapsulate the statement in an [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) block..

Comment: Thanks for the Tip!
But i think in the description something other should be done:
"If you wish for a warning instead, use the parameterized version of the finders"
It' really good that the parameter are not explained ...